# LINQ Query to get data from another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I am trying to write a LINQ Query where I want to select everything in Table 1 but instead of CaseStatusID, I want to return the actual status (Corresponding to CaseStatusID in Table 2).

I have the query but I the error `Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CaseId:int, Status:string>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Cases>'`

I have not been able to find a good example to help me. How can I achieve this?

```
    public List<Case> GetAllCases()
    {
        var result = (from c in _Context.Cases
                     join s in _Context.CaseStatus on c.CaseStatusId 
                     equals s.CaseStatusId
                     select new { c.CaseId, c.CaseStatu.Status }).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type doesn't match the declared return type `List<Case>`.  When you `select new {}`, you are actually returning an anonymous object from your linq expression.  You can fix it like this:

```
public List<Case> GetAllCases()
{
    var result = (from c in _Context.Cases
                 join s in _Context.CaseStatus on c.CaseStatusId 
                 equals s.CaseStatusId
                 select new Case { CaseId = c.CaseId, CaseStatus = c.CaseStatu.Status }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Note the `new Case{}` when selecting your data.  You may need to change `CaseId` and `CaseStatus` properties to match the actual properties from the `Case` class.

**Update**: To Clarify, you would need a `Case` class that looked minimally like this:

```
public class Case {
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: axlj, in your statement `CaseStatus = c.CaseStatu.Status`. In Table 1 I dont have anything called CaseStatus so I am not sure how it will work.

Comment: `CaseStatus` is the name of a property on the `Case` object.  `c.CaseStatu.Status` is the value from your table.

Comment: I am sorry if I did not clarify that. CaseStatus is actually the table (i.e Table 2).

Comment: Yes I dont have that. I dont think Its possible now without having that. But thank you for the answer

Comment: I can only do my best to infer based on the code provided.  You are joining two tables `Cases` and `CaseStatus` by the `Cases.CaseStatusId` field.  You are then selecting two fields from the result.  You need a C# object to represent those fields.  That is the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the select statement where you should return objects list of Case:

```
public List<Case> GetAllCases()
    {
        var result = (from c in _Context.Cases
                     join s in _Context.CaseStatus on c.CaseStatusId 
                     equals s.CaseStatusId
                     select new Case () { CaseId = c.CaseId, CaseStatusId = c.CaseStatusId  }).ToList();

        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating list of  annonymous type and returning list of case. that is the issue